# Download GCS object to your Vertex AI notebook in GCP

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, client, google-cloud-storage

If you have a gs:// blob, how do you download that file from GCS to Vertex AI notebook in GCP using python client library?

Comment: are you using a Google managed or user managed notebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download GCS file to Vertex AI notebook refer following python code:

```
from google.cloud import storage


def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # The ID of your GCS object
    # source_blob_name = "storage-object-name"      
    # destination_file_name = "/path/to/file"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print(
        "Downloaded storage object {} from bucket {} to file {}.".format(
            source_blob_name, bucket_name, destination_file_name
        )
    )
```

Alternatively, if you want to download GCS file to jupyter directory you can use the command:

`!gsutil cp gs://BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME JUPYTER_LOCATION`

Comment: I've tried this but I keep getting the error `OSError: Permission denied. KiB]`. I am using a managed workbook, is there some other set up I need to do? --fixed it, I was trying to download to a dest folder that didnt exist